# react-native naviguate between appcontainers

Tags: react-native, tabnavigator

The aim is to combine a BottomBarNavigator and a TopBarNavigator.
I want to put a NavigatorB (MaterialTopBarNavigator) inside a component (componentA) which is a screen of navigatorA (BottomTabNavigator).

To do that, I create a MaterialTopBarNavigator in my component and I wrapped it inside an AppContainer to use it in my render function.

In componentA:

```
const TabNavigator = createAppContainer(createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    screen1: { 
        screen: ComponentB,
    },
    screen2: {
        screen: ComponentB,
    }
}))

class ComponentA extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
        <View>
            //Some Stuff
            <TabNavigator />
        </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Now, I want to navigate from componentB to another screen from the navigator containing ComponentA: ComponentC

```
const MainTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
   MainScreen1: {
      screen: ComponentA 
   },
   MainScreen2: {
      screen: ComponentC
   }
}
```

Here is what I tried:

In ComponentB:

```
this.props.navigation.naviguate('MainScreen2', args)
```

So it does not work because props.navigation is inherited from the TabNavigator defined in ComponentA.

I searched for a way to pass the props.navigation of componentA to the TabNavigator (`<TabNavigator args=this.props.navigation>`) but couldn't find it.

I'm not sure if I am doing this right as I saw people advising to not create multiple appContainer [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/common-mistakes.html). But putting TabNavigator directly inside the MainTabNavigator put ComponentA inside the TabNavigator and that is not what I want because I want the "//Some Stuff" to be shared.

Thank you for your help in advance and don't hesitate to ask me more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way using [NavigationService](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html), I created the NavigationService for the MainTabNavigator and used it as specified in ComponentB.